# Mypy annotation on a class decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, mypy

I'm using class decorators in Python and cannot figure out which type annotation to give to my class to make **mypy** happy.

My code is the following:

```py
from typing import Type
from pprint import pformat


def betterrepr(cls:Type[object]):
    """Improve representation of a class"""

    class improved_class(cls):  # line 12
        def __repr__(self) -> str:
            return f"Instance of {cls.__name__}, vars = {pformat(vars(self))}"

    return improved_class
```

I'm currently having the 2 following errors:

> > myprog.py:12: error: Invalid type "cls"
> >
> > myprog.py:12: error: Invalid base class

What shall I use for the type of `cls` (and by the way, is it Pythonic to use this keyword for a class used as argument?)?

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can just *modify* ``cls`` instead of inheriting from it.

Comment: ``cls`` is the canonical name for classes, e.g. as the first argument to a ``classmethod``. "[...] 'cls' is the preferred spelling for any variable or argument which is known to be a class, especially the first argument to a class method." from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: For typical class decorators that just modify the class and do not create new type: Mypy uses plugins for this kind of behavior. For class decorators you can use the [dataclass plugin](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py) as reference. For Pyright (fast type checker by Microsoft) you can use [dataclass transforms](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/specs/dataclass_transforms.md).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using function arguments as base classes is [currently not supported by `mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5865). Your only option is to silence the error, either with a `type: ignore` comment or a dummy alias like `base: Any = cls`.

Even without annotating `cls`, `mypy` will correctly infer the type of a class decorated with `betterrepr`. To document that your decorator returns a class similar to the decorated class, use a `TypeVar`.

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar
from pprint import pformat

T = TypeVar('T')


def betterrepr(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
    """Improve representation of a class"""
    class IClass(cls):  # type: ignore
        def __repr__(self) -> str:
            return f"Instance of {cls.__name__}, vars = {pformat(vars(self))}"
    return IClass
```