# Mypy doesn't recognize class decorator

Tags: python, mypy, typing

### Problem

Suppose I want to implement a class decorator that adds some attributes and functions to an existing class.

In particular, let's say I have a protocol called `HasNumber`, and I need a decorator `can_add` that adds the missing methods to convert `HasNumber` class to `CanAdd`.

```
class HasNumber(Protocol):
    num: int

class CanAdd(HasNumber):
    def add(self, num: int) -> int: ...
```

### Implementation

I implement the decorator as follows:

```
_HasNumberT = TypeVar("_HasNumberT", bound=HasNumber)


def can_add(cls: Type[_HasNumberT]) -> Type[CanAdd]:
    def add(self: _HasNumberT, num: int) -> int:
        return self.num + num

    setattr(cls, "add", add)

    return cast(Type[CanAdd], cls)


@can_add
class Foo:
    num: int = 12
```

### Error

The code works just fine when I run it, but mypy is unhappy about it for some reason.

It gives the error `"Foo" has no attribute "add"  [attr-defined]`, as if it doesn't take the return value (annotated as `Type[CanAdd]`) of the `can_add` decorator into account.

```
foo = Foo()
print(foo.add(4))  # "Foo" has no attribute "add"  [attr-defined]
reveal_type(foo) # note: Revealed type is "test.Foo"
```

### Question

In this [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3135#issuecomment-388566366), someone demonstrated a way of annotating this with `Intersection`. However, is there a way to achieve it without `Intersection`? (Supposing that I don't care about other attributes in `Foo` except the ones defined in the protocols)

Or, is it a limitation of mypy itself?

Related posts that don't solve my problem:

- [Mypy annotation on a class decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855356/mypy-annotation-on-a-class-decorator)
- [Class Decorator Compatible for Mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065631/class-decorator-compatible-for-mypy)

Comment: I suspect it's a shortcoming of `mypy`. `cast` suppresses any concerns that the thing being returned isn't a `CanAdd`, but there is no static guarantee provided that  `add` was actually added to the `cls` argument.

Comment: As a result, `mypy` cannot confirm that `Foo` has an `add` attribute, only that you are saying it's OK for `Foo` (with or without an `add` attribute) to be the return value of `can_add`.

Comment: What I expected from mypy is that it substitutes the decorated class with the return type of `can_add`, i.e. `Type[CanAdd]`, without concerning about what's actually going on with the actual implementation (since I intentionally ignore it with `cast`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cast` tells `mypy` that `cls` (with or without an `add` attribute) is safe to use as the return value for `can_add`. It does *not* guarantee that the protocol holds.

As a result, `mypy` cannot tell whether `Foo` has been given an `add` attribute, only that it's OK to use the `can_add` decorator. The fact that `can_add` has a side effect of defining the `add` attribute isn't visible to `mypy`.

You can, however, replace the decorator with direct inheritance, something like

```
class HasNumber(Protocol):
    num: int


_HasNumberT = TypeVar("_HasNumberT", bound=HasNumber)

class Adder(HasNumber):
    def add(self, num: int) -> int:
        return self.num + num

class Foo(Adder):
    num: int = 12

foo = Foo()
print(foo.add(4))
```

Comment: Yes, inheritance might be the best solution here. Perhaps there will be better support to class decorators in the future. (As a side-note reconfirming that it might be a mypy limitation, Pylance correctly types the decorated class)